# I am having an issue to create a dropdown menu in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

[I am trying to create a dropdown menu from "about us" but there seems to be some color unabling to give a proper dropdown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ALF.png) On the navigation bar there's a block of red color next to the "Home" button. Also when i hover on the "About us" button there are again red color visible therefore not aligning the dropdown menu links. Can someone explains how to remove the additional color? Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<br>
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: TIMES ROMAN;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #330000;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text], .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  }
}
</style>

<body style="background-color:#C0C0C0">

<div class="topnav">
  <img src="D1.jpg" height="70" width="120" align="left"><br>
   <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><a class="active">About us
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Who are we?</a>
          <a href="#">What do we do</a>
          <a href="#">Project aims/goals</a>
          <a href="#">History</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
     <a href="#contact">Contact ✆</a>
     <a href="#about">Gallery </a>
     <a href="#about">Our services</a>
     <a href="#about">Policy</a>
     <a href="#about">Sign Up</a>
     
<div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you code your `css` is different then how you have the `html` structure.

```html
<a class="active"><button class="dropbtn">About us <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button></a>
```

Check the above line and replace it in your code.
Wrap your `button` element inside `a` (anchor) tag.